# workspace local conf for pylsp

Tags: python-3.x, python-language-server

My project has an unusual layout

How do I get pylsp to use a configuration that is local to my workspace ?
I'd like it to find my libraries, my stub files and my code (all of them are in specific subfolders)

On their [home page](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server), I find

> Overall configuration is computed first from user configuration (in
> home directory), overridden by configuration passed in by the language
> client, and then overridden by configuration discovered in the
> workspace.

How do I get a configuration that can be "discovered" in the workspace ?

Comment: do you find a solution?

Comment: not yet

I gave up on the unusual layout

I'm gonna try again in the second half of september and october